# How to use a mathematic equation to stop object going off screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[SOLVED]

I've been following the Learn To Code By Making Games course (Block Breaker Section) from Udemy and I have a flippin' annoying issue. My paddle doesn't clamp properly to the values I put in. I would have had no trouble with this but I decided that I want a small menu on the left side with a speed controller, sound controller and lives. This means I cant just say that I want the paddle to stop on the edge of the screen.

**​Observed Behavior:**

​The paddle does not constrain itself to the area I put in. As the screen size changes the paddle will either go off the screen or will be stopped somewhere like the middle of the screen.

**​What I Want It To Do:**

​I want the paddle to stop when it hits the edge of my menu on the left and to stop when it hits the screen on the right. I also want this to stay the same as my screen size changes. So basically I need a mathematic equation that can determine these points and it needs to be able to adjust based on the screen size.

**Here is my code for the paddle:​**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture texture;

    public void Update () {

        Vector3 paddlePos = new Vector3 (0.5f, this.transform.position.y , 0f);

        float mousePosInBlocks = Input.mousePosition.x;

        paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp(mousePosInBlocks, //Left Vaule, //Right Value);

        this.transform.position = paddlePos;
    }
}
```

Comment: The behavior depends on how you are computing the "//Left Vaule" and "//Right Value" and it's impossible to answer without this information. Also I would not be so quick to say "Mathf.Clamp is not working" but re-checked the arguments passed instead.

Comment: Good point, I changed the title. Any ideas on how I could do it still?

Comment: @MatthewInglis If one of the answers provided brought you to the solution, please accept it by clicking the grey checkmark next to the answer. Otherwise, please post your own to show others how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because Input.mousePosition returns position of mouse on screen, not in world space. just convert mousePosition into world position, and then assign its value to mousePosInBlocks.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture texture;

    public void Update () {

        Vector3 paddlePos = new Vector3 (0.5f, this.transform.position.y , 0f);

        float mousePosInBlocks = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;

        paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp(mousePosInBlocks, leftValue, rightValue);

        this.transform.position = paddlePos;
    }
}
```

Edit: Sorry, not WorldToScreenPoint, ScreenToWorldPoint

Comment: Thanks so much, but what value should I put in for the Mathf.Clamp? I have tried a fixed value, a percentage, screen.width...all without success.

Comment: Mathf.Clamp sets the boundaries for value. it depends where you want paddle to be. for example you are working on a world space with 16 unit x, and 10 unit y. And position of camera is (0,0,-10), you have a paddle which width of 2 unit. So your leftValue should be -8 (left edge of world space), and rightValue should be -6 (left edge + width of paddle). of course these are values for paddle on left.

Comment: Ok, I have followed what you said. Here is what I got: World space is 1920 (x), 1080 (y), and the paddle has a width of 200. And I set the camera to what you said in the example. So my leftValue is -960 and rightValue is -760. I have put these in but they didn't work...

Comment: no, 1920(x) and 1080(y) is your screen space. look at grids on your scene, each grid is 1 unit in world space. for an easier way to get world space (y) look at your MainCamera's size at inspector. it is probably '5' and this means you have 10 unit (5 is under x axis and 5 is above x axis) on (y). so you have apprxmately 17.7 unit on (x). you should look how many grids your paddle's width. if it's sprite and has a width of 200 it should be probably 2 in worldspace. so your left value should be -8.8 (17.7 / -2)  and right value -6.8 ( -8.8 +2)

Answer (score 0):

Try just setting the paddlePos to the new vector you're creating (in world space):

```
public Texture texture; // if needed for something outside this code
private Vector3 paddlePos;
private float mousePosInBlocks;
private float xValue;
private float leftValue;
private float rightValue;

public void Update () {

    mousePosInBlocks = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;
    //compute leftValue on this line
    //compute rightValue on this line

    xValue = Mathf.Clamp(mousePosInBlocks, leftValue, rightValue);

    paddlePos = new Vector3 (xValue, transform.position.y , 0f);

    transform.position = paddlePos;
}
```

**EDIT** Based on updated question title, the following should work:

```
public Texture texture; // if needed for something outside this code
private Vector3 playerPosOnScreen;
private float mousePosInBlocks;

public void Update () {

    playerPosOnScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

    if (playerPosOnScreen.x > Screen.Width) {

        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Screen.Width, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

    } else if (playerPosOnScreen.x < 0f) {

        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (0f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thats for the edit. However monodevelop  doesnt like it, its given me a bunch of errors. Here is a screenshot from monodevelop of the errors (http://i.imgur.com/VQZr01N.png)

Comment: Sorry about that, there was an extra closing brace in Update(). Try now?

Comment: @MatthewInglis Great, if you feel like I answered your question, please mark this as the answer... if I was helpful, please up vote so others will know it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: (pseudo code, untested, to give you an idea)

Please check the comment for each step.

```
public void Update () {

        // left bound
        Vector3 left = Camera.main.ViewPortToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f));

        // Menu width
        left.x += fmyMenuWidth; // Width of menu

        // Right bound
        Vector3 right= Camera.main.ViewPortToScreenPoint(new Vector3(1f, 1f, 0f));

        // Temporary position vector    
        Vector3 paddlePos = Vector3.zero;

        // capture mouse x
        float mouseX = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;

        // capture mouse y
        float mouseY= Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y;

        // Combine and limit the position's X-value, should not go off screen menu's width---->screen's width
        paddlePos.x = Mathf.Max(Mathf.Min(right.x, mouseX), left.x);

        // Combine and limit the position's Y-value, should not go off screen 0---->screen's height
        paddlePos.y = Mathf.Max(Mathf.Min(right.y, mouseY), left.y);

        // Finally set the bounded position
        this.transform.position = paddlePos;
}
```